# Need Batch File to close a Window.. NOT the batch window

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

Complete novice here so please forgive if the answer is obvious.

I have a batch file that does the following.

Starts program 1
Waits 3 seconds (I have to click a button on program 1 after it opens)
Then program 2 starts.

My problem is that program 1 just needs to run in the background.... No window needed after the first 3 seconds.

Normally, I start the batch file, program 1 starts.
I click the button to start a service.

Three seconds the second program starts.

I then have to go back to program 1 and click the X in top right of window to close it. I'd like for the WINDOW on program one to close automatically after 3 seconds (but the program itself cannot be killed).

Suggestions?

```
@echo off
start C:\Folder\To\MySystemManager.exe
TIMEOUT 3

start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\CustomProgram\CustomProgram.exe"
exit
```

Comment: Please post the content of your batch file so we can help troubleshoot.

Comment: Can you try the delay options in Windows Task Scheduler and check your results. You can make a batch file to run at a particular delay on an action triggered in your machine. You need to think little and apply a sort solution that can make some delay to start and close the program.

Comment: Posted code. Not sure I follow you on the need for a delay. I have that. What I need is a command to essentially close a Window (but not the task/program" that has the title "MySystemManager" or something along that line.... I think.

Comment: Not sure why you do not provide obligatory `"title"` parameter in the first `start`? Try the same as in second use: `start "" C:\Folder\To\MySystemManager.exe`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK that's not possible with 'pure' batch - you'd need to use either a 3rd party tool or use powershell [or some other way to reference Win API].

If I understood you correctly and the window you want to close is a kind of a control panel which redefines Window close  message than this should work (as run from cmd and assuming there is only one instance of the process):

`powershell (ps MySystemManager).CloseMainWindow()`

This command acts as if you'd clicked 'close' (<kbd>X</kbd>) button

I have tested it with xampp control panel (`powershell (ps xampp-control).CloseMainWindow()`), your mileage may vary

Comment: You are brilliant! I know I'm a novice but I have done dozens of Google searches and have found nothing that explained how to do this. I didn't even know you could enable power shell in a .bat file. Anyway, thanks a lot. I really appreciate it.