# Exclude one windowtitle from taskkill command

Tags: cmd.exe

i want to terminate a process but one windowtitle should be excluded.
so basically in a browser every window get killed except the one i want to stay open.

taskkill /IM msedge.exe /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq windowtitle" = exclusion

any idea how the batch file have to look like?
thanks for the help in advanche :)

Comment: `taskkill /IM msedge.exe /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE ne exclusion"` See `taskkill /?`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I do not think that is possible with a batch file.

You should, for example, use AutoIt instead.

Another option is PowerShell, see [Need Batch File to close a Window.. NOT the batch window](https://superuser.com/questions/859043/need-batch-file-to-close-a-window-not-the-batch-window) (but I wouldn't recommend that because I hate PowerShell).

Comment: how i can do it with autoit?

Comment: Here is the documentation which contains an example 
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinClose.htm

Comment: ok i know that but my problem is i want to close the "new tab" window and if i call Run(@ComSpec & ' /c start msedge --inprivate --window-size=10,10 --window-position=955,535 --app="url',@SW_HIDE) ..it opens an extra new tab window sometimes.. and thats why i want to close each instance except the one i call here

Comment: and the windowtitle(new tab) is specified in languages ..so i want to kill all except the one window i want to be open bc it should work in different countries

Comment: I think you should check out Stack Overflow. Superuser.com is not for programming questions, but Stack Overflow is! Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/tour and https://stackoverflow.com/help first.

Comment: ok thank you ..